# httpClient request is called twice in angular4

Tags: angular, apache-httpclient-4.x

I call API in my angular4 application using httpClient, but the API is called twice, the first call method is OPTIONS while the second is Get.

**Component.ts:-**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './Services/User.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'user-component',
  templateUrl: './user-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-component.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  apiResponse : any;
  status      : any = 'active';

  constructor(private service: UserService) { } 

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getResult();
  }

  getResult()
  {
     this.service.getUser(this.status)
     .subscribe(res => {this.apiResponse = res},
                err => console.log(err),
                ()  => console.log(this.apiResponse)  
              );

  }
}
```

**Component.html:-**

```
<pre>{{apiResponse |json}}</pre>
```

**User.service.ts:-**

```
import { Injectable,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

interface Response {
  response : any;
}

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  apiUrl : any='http://localhost/MyProject/';
  constructor( private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getUser(status: any)
  {
     let httpParams = new HttpParams().set('status', status);
     return this.http.get<Response>(this.apiUrl+"users", {params: httpParams}).map(response => response.response);
  }
}
```

The API is called twice, please tell me how solve this problem?

Comment: That's not related to Angular in any way. The OPTIONS request is made by the browser when it recognizes a CORS situation. The OPTIONS request expects the headers in the resonse from the server it mentions in the error message if it doesn't get them. If the response is as expected the browser makes the actual request. This can only be fixed on the server.

Comment: @Harleen Kaur Arora.... Did you fix this?

Comment: @Omar.... I did not found any solutions.

Comment: no fix but will get to it in about a week

Comment: Ok, If this issue fixed, Please tell me.

Comment: This isn't an issue and it can't be fixed. This is a wanted behavior.

Comment: By the way, when you mark an answer as resolved, don't remove the mark unless you have a **better answer**, instead of *some dude asking for your help for the same question*. I'll remember you for that.

Answer (score 3):

`OPTIONS` requests are automatic. You can't avoid it.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)

> The HTTP OPTIONS method is used to describe the communication options for the target resource. The client can specify a specific URL for the OPTIONS method, or an asterisk (*) to refer to the entire server.